# Draw button diagram using html5 and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to migrate desktop application to webbase. Which have button diagram like picture below.

[image: buttons diagram]

All button doesn't dragable. I just want to connect them with line. This may a silly question. But I am new in web development. I read some advice that i can use html canvas or using js library. But, I don't know how or where to start. Or is this possible using html5 and jquery only without any plugin?
 Or even pure html5?
Please help.

Comment: you can use divs to look like a button why draw it using canvas?

Comment: @RRR Can you give me some suggestion how to do that?

Comment: if possible will create a demo and show gimme some time

Comment: Where are fourth level connected to third level?

Comment: @guest271314 Its static. and third level (FAD3) does not connected to (Penetapan Anggaran). Its all button, which when I clicked a button, its execute some code.

Comment: you can use button tags and position it as per your design and for lines you can use divs... or you can use divs as button... here is a small sample https://jsfiddle.net/01e3w032/

Comment: See [`<table>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table) element

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions for this problem:

1. Either you will have to draw the whole structure using button tags and html5 canvas, or
2. just make a div, place your image(which already has the structure) in its background and absolutely position the button tags where you want them to be.

I'll recommend the second solution, it is quick fix. Below I have mention an example for the reference

```css
  div{
   background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bw9Zj.jpg) no-repeat;
   height: 300px;
   width: 800px;
  }
  button {
      position: absolute;
      top: 57px;
      left: 306px;
      width: 161px;
      height: 29px;
  }
```

```html
 <div></div>
 <button>Switch the kenator</button>
```